# Unable to read multiline file using spark with scala encoding -ISo-8859-1 (Spark 3.0)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read one **CSV** file with *MultiLine= true* but the results are not coming properly .

```
val df = spark.read.format("csv") \
.option("header", "fale") \
.option("multiline", "true") \
.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1") \
.option("lineSep", "\u000A")
.option("delimiter", "\u0001")
.csv("path/to/csv/file.csv")
```

The data still coming in multiple row  . In file line separator is $(\u000A) . Null columns are also available .

> Currently Spark 2.0 does not support encoding